# python tab delimited retrieve column and delete empty lines

Tags: python, csv

I have a tab delimited text file that is consists of two columns, something like:

```
Apple123    2
Orange933   2
Banana33334 2
```

There maybe empty lines at the bottom. How can I:
1. Strip the empty lines, and
2. write to a file that consists only the first column?

My problem right now is that if I use **line.strip()** then the line consists of a list that has the length of 10 (for example for the first line) not 2. If I use **csv.reader**(..., dialect = excel-tab) then I can't use strip() so I can't get rid of the empty lines.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
with open(infilename) as infile, open(outfilename) as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            outfile.write("{}\n".format(line.split("\t")[0]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe do this with Python's basic string manipulation (`str.split` and so on):

```
infile = open("/path/to/myfile.txt")
outfile = open("/path/to/output.txt", "w") # Clears existing file, open for writing

for line in infile:
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
        # skip blank lines
        continue

    # Get first column, write it to file
    col1 = line.split("\t")[0]
    outfile.write(col1 + "\n")

outfile.close()
```

Comment: You're usually better off with just `for line in infile:`.

Comment: @mgilson good point, edited. I can never seem to remember that the default file iterator is `readlines`..

Comment: it's deeper than that.  `readlines()` returns a list.  the other way, you're reading the files lazily.  In other words, `readlines()` reads the whole file up front whereas `__iter__` does not.

Comment: @mgilson oh, true - I assumed readlines was a generator, but that behaviour makes far more sense. Time to re-read the `file` docs I think :P

Comment: You could use `xreadlines` to get a generator, but that is kind of ugly. `for line in infile` is best.